# How to work with progress bar in VB.Net win form application

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to transfer files from one directory to another using streamreader and writer class. Now i want to add a statusbar to show the filename on statusbar along with the remaining percentage. It will reach 100 when file has been moved to new directory. Any suggestions please?

```
  Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")
  Dim ioLine As String
  Dim ioLines As String
  ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
 ioLines = ioLine
 While Not ioLine = ""
     ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
     ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine
  End While
 Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")
 ioWriter.WriteLine(ioLines)
 ioFile.Close()
 ioWriter.Close()
```

Comment: You should copy bytes, not strings.  And you should write as you read instead of building a giant buffer.

Comment: please don't re-post the same question. Be patient and good things will come. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saif Kahn is right, if you are just copying a file, then just copy a file.  But to answer your question, here is a progress bar:

```
Dim tmpLines() as String = File.ReadAllLines("c:\sample.csv")
ProgressBar1.Maximum = tmpLines.Count - 1
ProgressBar1.Value = 0
For tmpRun As Integer = 0 To tmpLines.Count - 1
  ProgressBar1.Value += 1

  'Copy Stuff
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    ' Copy the file to a new folder, overwriting existing file.
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile( _
    "C:\UserFiles\TestFiles\testFile.txt", _
    "C:\UserFiles\TestFiles2\testFile.txt", _
    FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, _
    FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

> The [My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwfbss93%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
>   method allows you to copy files. Its
>   parameters provide the ability to
>   overwrite existing files, rename the
>   file, show the progress of the
>   operation, and allow the user to
>   cancel the operation

Comment: I need to add a statusbar control which will display the progress. can I get any suggestion in that way.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I am in a bit hurry and asked wrongly. I need to add progressbar not statusbar. If anybody knows please help me

Comment: scroll to the bottom of this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx hope that helps.